# Adding attributes to a Webpack module at build time

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

In my Webpack configuration, I want to specify a couple attributes that I want to add to my module.

For example, I want to add `x` and `y` at build time to `MyModule`, giving me `MyModule.x` and `MyModule.y`.

Is this possible without creating my own Webpack plug-in?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)?  It's what most libs use to enable certain features at compile time like Vue will have you enable DEV tools support.

Comment: DefinePlugin doesn't quite do what I need: It doesn't add attributes to my module that consumers can read—it just provides variables that my module can use within itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [provide-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

> Automatically load modules instead of having to import or require them
> everywhere.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  identifier: ['module1', 'property1'],
  // ...
});
```

this is class definion

```
declare class ProvidePlugin {
    constructor(definitions: Record<string, string | string[]>);
    definitions: Record<string, string | string[]>;

    /**
     * Apply the plugin
     */
    apply(compiler: Compiler): void;
}
```

Looks like if you want to pass multiple values, you need to pass inside an array.

that pluign is used to add polyfills in webpack5 manually

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   process: "process/browser",
   Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
   React: "react",
}),
```

Comment: ProvidePlugin doesn't quite do what I need: It doesn't itself add attributes to a module—it just provides values to pre-existing variables.

Comment: Couldn't you assign the pre-existing variables to the module and then use `ProvidePlugin` to define the modules? I don't know your exact use case, but it sounds like that would cover a lot of use cases.

Comment: I have a mono-repo with a lot of modules, and I would prefer not to litter each module with several attributes that I want to add to each if I could do it once through Webpack itself.